# Fedora terminal script to create a directory and copy a file to directory

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, mkdir

I need help to write a script to create a directory, so far I have `mkdir ./directory`.

This would create a folder called **Directory**, but I need to make it ask if the user wants to copy a file called **File.txt** to this directory.

And then I need to make the file to have read, write and execute permission.

Comment: So what specific part are you having problems with?

Comment: check https://maker.pro/linux/tutorial/basic-linux-commands-for-beginnerson for basic CLI commands

Comment: What is the command to move a certain file to a certain directory?

Comment: it's as simple as `mv`, check the article I've pointed you to.

Comment: In the question, you said "copy a file to this directory" but in a follow-up comment, you ask "how to move a file to a directory". Those are different operations.

Answer (score 1):

I follow your statements:

1. Create a dir
2. Ask to user if he wants to copy file.txt into dir
3. Set correct permission on that file (rwx)

Create a bash script:

```
touch script.sh
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Paste below code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script that create a directory and move a file with rwx privileges

# Variables
directory_path="directory"
filename="file.txt"


# Create the directory
mkdir -- "$directory_path"

# Check if user want copy the file
read -p "Do you want copy $filename in $directory_path? [y/n]" input

if [ "$input" = y ]; then
    echo "Copying $filename to $directory_path"
    cp -- "$filename" "$directory_path/$filename"
    chmod 774 "$directory_path/$filename"
elif [ "$input" = n ]; then
    echo "Nothing to do, goodbye"
    exit
else
    echo "Incorrect input"
    exit 1
fi
```

You can modify filename and directory path with listed variables:

```
# Variables
directory_path="directory"
filename="file.txt"
```

Comment: tip: use `mkdir -p` -- that way there will be no errors if the directory already exists.